# multipal google maps overlapping

Tags: javascript, maps

I have two maps loading

```
<body onload="startup(); initialize()">
```

The problem is one just overlaps they are not merging. Any ideals on what to look for?

Comment: I call the maps by 
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>
<div id="map_canvas1" ></div>

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please provide some more information in your question.